# Filter a string from HTML tags expect <bla> tag in php

Tags: php, html

I want to disallow all HTML tags in a string expect some tags , I have tried this code :

```
 <?php
 $Bla = htmlspecialchars_decode("<script>alert('XSS Vuln.');</script>
    <font>Black Hawk Text Here ^_^</font>
    <h1>jhdasflkasdfjkasfd</h1>");
 echo $Black;
```

the output of this code is :

[image]

Note : The  tag disabled , i want to be able to use it without using and othe tag

Comment: Use just `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: @Thamilan It has disabled every think in the text :\

Comment: Thank you bro the problem has fixed just using `htmlspecialchars_decode`

Comment: `htmlspecialchars_decode` will decode all encoded entities, you don't have any of the those in your example. Also `$Black` is undefined.

Comment: `$Black` is `$Bla`

Comment: `htmlspecialchars_decode` helped my with disable every think may can hack my site like : `<script>alert('XSS Vuln.');</script>` and allow me to use the style tags like `<font>Black Hawk Text Here ^_^</font>` and `<h1>jhdasflkasdfjkasfd</h1>`

Comment: and this is all what i want ^_^